# Why would you copy your Gemfile.lock into Docker, then immediately overwrite it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, bundler

Why would you copy `Gemfile.lock`, run `bundle install` to create a new `Gemfile.lock`, then immediately copy the current directory which contains the original `Gemfile.lock` and overwrite the `Gemfile.lock` that was just created by Bundler within the Docker container?

Also why can you get away with not having `EXPOSE 3000`?

https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/#define-the-project

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /myapp
```

That isn't the only place it does that. It's also done here, which seems pretty official. Maybe I'm missing a fundamental aspect of Docker?

https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/

```
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install

COPY . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to the second part of this question:

> Also why can you get away with not having EXPOSE 3000?

The full `Dockerfile` that you referenced does contain this line:

`EXPOSE 3000`

Comment: The documentation seems to have been incomplete when I wrote this question. There wasn't an `EXPOSE 3000` in there.

Comment: @Chloe thanks for replying, makes sense.  If you edit the original question that would be awesome for the next person.

Answer (score 5):

More a guess than an answer, but sometimes you order the steps in `Dockerfile`s slightly differently to improve the caching mechanism. When you change things in your application, it's less likely that it will affect the `Gemfile`s, so you don't have to do a `bundle install` after everything you change. Ordering the steps in this way avoids having to execute `bundle install` for changes to your application that do not affect the `Gemfile`s.

Documentation on build caching: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#build-cache

Comment: I think this is the right answer. If you rebuild you docker image and there have been no changes to the Gemfile then this (lengthy) step is skipped.